# SQL SUM meny values in table column record a single query

Tags: mysql, laravel

I want sum total of oiltype

```
where fullname = gift and 
      FDate = '01-10-2023' and vehicalType = 'car'
```

Also  sum total of oiltype

```
where fullname = 'gift' and 
      FDate = '01-10-2023' and vehicalType = 'motorcycle'
```

In single query.

I'm write this code but not work.

```
Select vehicalType, sum(total) as total ,fullname, FDate  
from paking_histories 
where FDate = '01-10-2023' and oiltype ='oil' and Fullname ='gift';
```

Results needed.

```
Car      motorcycle     date 
Total     total        01-10-2023
```

Comment: Please add sample data if possible

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your source data that should yield the posted result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the conditional aggregation :

```
select sum(case when vehicalType = 'car' then total else 0 end) as car,
       sum(case when vehicalType = 'motorcycle' then total else 0 end) as motorcycle,
       FDate 
from paking_histories
where FDate = '2023-10-01' and oiltype ='oil' and Fullname ='gift'
```